# Styling multiple buttons at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, widget, pyqt5

Consider the following toy example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("1")
        btn1.setStyleSheet('''QPushButton {background-color : red;}
                              QPushButton:!hover {background-color: grey;}''')

        btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("2")
        btn2.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color : green;}')

        btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("3")
        btn3.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color : blue;}')

        layout.addWidget(btn1)
        layout.addWidget(btn2)
        layout.addWidget(btn3)

        self.show()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

As you can see, I can instruct any individual button to stay grey when the mouse does not hover above it with the following:

```
QPushButton:!hover {background-color: grey;}
```

I woud like *all* buttons in the layout to remain grey when I am not hovering above the widget and change to their color at the same time when the mouse enters the widget area.

I tried adding the line below but it does not work:

```
w.setStyleSheet('QPushButton:!hover {background-color: gray;}')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option, try this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("1")
        btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("2")
        btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("3")

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)
        layout.addWidget(btn1)
        layout.addWidget(btn2)
        layout.addWidget(btn3)


style = """

QPushButton {
    background-color: grey;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background-color : red;
}
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app.setStyleSheet(style)                         # +++
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

---

**Update**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("1")
        btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("2")
        btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("3")

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)
        layout.addWidget(btn1)
        layout.addWidget(btn2)
        layout.addWidget(btn3)


style = """

QPushButton {
    background-color: grey;
}
QPushButton[text='1']:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
QPushButton[text='2']:hover {
    background-color : green;
}
QPushButton[text='3']:hover {
    background-color : blue;
}
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app.setStyleSheet(style)                         # +++
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

---

**Update 2**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.w)

        self.w.installEventFilter(self)

        btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("1")
        btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("2")
        btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("3")

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.w)
        layout.addWidget(btn1)
        layout.addWidget(btn2)
        layout.addWidget(btn3)

        self.setStyleSheet("""        
            QPushButton[text='1'] {
                background-color: grey;
            }
            QPushButton[text='2'] {
                background-color : grey;
            }
            QPushButton[text='3'] {
                background-color : grey;
            }        
        """) 


    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
            self.setStyleSheet("""        
                QPushButton[text='1'] {
                    background-color: red;
                }
                QPushButton[text='2'] {
                    background-color : green;
                }
                QPushButton[text='3'] {
                    background-color : blue;
                }        
            """)      
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:  
            self.setStyleSheet("""        
                QPushButton[text='1'] {
                    background-color: grey;
                }
                QPushButton[text='2'] {
                    background-color : grey;
                }
                QPushButton[text='3'] {
                    background-color : grey;
                }        
            """)         
        return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you but this is not what I meant. I want all buttons within a specific widget to revert to their individual colours when i hover anywhere within the area of widget in question. When the mouse is not in the widget they should be grey.

Comment: This reverts only one button and when someone hovers on it. I want all three buttons revert back to their colors (red, green, blue) simultaneously when hovering anywhere on w not just a specific button. I hope this is clearer now. :-)